# Not able to record the wep application when the url name is having special character in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```
 we are using two URL for our web application .
```

One URL is having Special character and
     another one does not have the special character. Without Special Character url , I am 
     to record the script but while using with Special character URL , I am not able to 
     record the script.

```
    EX : http://test-qa.test.com -- not able to record the script
         http://test.test.com - able to record the script 
     Please suggest and help to record the scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

JMeter proxy should not have any problems with recording URLs with `-` sign, i.e. I can successfully record https://jmeter-plugins.org/ site browsing

[image: JMeter dash recording]

So the problem must reside somewhere else.

You can try out the following options:

1. Create recording test plan using [JMeter Templates feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template). It will automatically populate the good recording configuration.
2. Consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) instead of JMeter built-in proxy.

Comment: IF I give the http://test-qa.test.com kind of URL , I did not get any response in the browser. only showing the blank page. please let me know whether it could be issue with the server or let me know the exact steps to resolve this issue